# Is there a more efficient way to create images using python PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to generate an image that contains the text of a given string. For now I'm using the Image.draw.text() from the Pyhton PIL library to generate the result and the process is working fine, but it's exceedingly slow and it takes a handful of seconds to finish drawing, which is really hampering the scalability of the program.

This is the current function to generate images:

```
def draw_ascii(ascii_image, new_width) :
    # Source text, and wrap it.
    adjusted_ascii = ascii_image.replace("\n", " ")
    text = textwrap.fill(adjusted_ascii, new_width)

    # Font size, color and type.
    fontcolor = (0, 0, 0)
    fontsize = 14
    font = ImageFont.truetype("FreeMono.ttf", fontsize)

    # Determine text size using a scratch image.
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (1,1))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    textsize = draw.textsize(text, font)

    # Creating the final image and put the text on it
    background = (255, 255, 255)
    img = Image.new("RGB", textsize, background)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((0, 0), text, fontcolor, font)

    return(img)
```

Comment: I don't know if it would be enough to make a significant difference, but you could certainly speed up this code by creating the font and the 1x1 scratch image *once* per run of the program, rather than recreating them for each image you generate.

Comment: I tried modifying the function to avoid recreating that(pretty much removed the section between fontcolor and textsize from the function) and didn't noticed any significant improvements to the runtime. The problem really seems to be in the final part of the code